# How to create a TCA field for uploading a PDF file to SQL `mediumblob` in TYPO3 10.4

Tags: typo3, blob, typo3-extensions

I am trying to find solution, that will allow user to upload PDF file via TCA. Uploaded file musn't create relation with `sys_file_reference`.

My current code in TCA:

```
    'pdf_data' => [
        'exclude' => true,
        'label' => 'PDF file',
        'config' => \TYPO3\CMS\Core\Utility\ExtensionManagementUtility::getFileFieldTCAConfig(
            'pdf_file',
            [
                'appearance' => [
                    'createNewRelationLinkTitle' => 'Add PDF file',
                ],
                'maxitems' => 1,
                'minitems' => 0,
                'overrideChildTca' => [
                    'types' => [
                        '0' => [
                            'showitem' => '
                        --palette--;LLL:EXT:lang/locallang_tca.xlf:sys_file_reference.imageoverlayPalette;imageoverlayPalette,
                        --palette--;;filePalette'
                        ],
                        \TYPO3\CMS\Core\Resource\File::FILETYPE_TEXT => [
                            'showitem' => '
                        --palette--;LLL:EXT:lang/locallang_tca.xlf:sys_file_reference.imageoverlayPalette;imageoverlayPalette,
                        --palette--;;filePalette'
                        ],
                        \TYPO3\CMS\Core\Resource\File::FILETYPE_IMAGE => [
                            'showitem' => '
                        --palette--;LLL:EXT:lang/locallang_tca.xlf:sys_file_reference.imageoverlayPalette;imageoverlayPalette,
                        --palette--;;filePalette'
                        ],
                        \TYPO3\CMS\Core\Resource\File::FILETYPE_AUDIO => [
                            'showitem' => '
                        --palette--;LLL:EXT:lang/locallang_tca.xlf:sys_file_reference.imageoverlayPalette;imageoverlayPalette,
                        --palette--;;filePalette'
                        ],
                        \TYPO3\CMS\Core\Resource\File::FILETYPE_VIDEO => [
                            'showitem' => '
                        --palette--;LLL:EXT:lang/locallang_tca.xlf:sys_file_reference.imageoverlayPalette;imageoverlayPalette,
                        --palette--;;filePalette'
                        ],
                        \TYPO3\CMS\Core\Resource\File::FILETYPE_APPLICATION => [
                            'showitem' => '
                        --palette--;LLL:EXT:lang/locallang_tca.xlf:sys_file_reference.imageoverlayPalette;imageoverlayPalette,
                        --palette--;;filePalette'
                        ],
                    ],
                ],
                'filter' => [
                    '0' => [
                        'parameters' => [
                            'allowedFileExtensions' => 'pdf'
                        ]
                    ]
                ],
                'default' => null,
            ],
            'pdf'
        ),
    ]
],
```

Comment: There is no such function in TYPO3. File content is saved as file and not in database. What's the reason you need this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Although Thomas already stated, that it is very uncommon and you really need a good reason to store PDF files in a database, you could still try to provide your own form engine rendering via `TCA` column type `user`

https://docs.typo3.org/m/typo3/reference-tca/10.4/en-us/ColumnsConfig/Type/User.html

Just make sure to provide a render type, that will return basic information about the stored data, so that BE users will get a convenient user interface to deal with the files.

Additionally you might want to deal with the data while it gets stored, so providing methods for the `DataHandler` would be necessary too.

https://docs.typo3.org/m/typo3/reference-coreapi/main/en-us/ApiOverview/Typo3CoreEngine/Introduction/Index.html